# Como borrar una carpeta o todos los archivos de una carpeta, en storage firebase 9?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

La documentación oficial es antigua y no he encontrado información útil al respecto.

He intentado lo siguiente sin resultados:

```
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const store = getStorage(firebaseConfig)
const storeRef = ref(store, `post/${id}`)
await deleteObject(storeRef)
```

La ruta de la carpeta es: /post/${id}/...files...

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto... v9 de la página oficial de firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files?hl=ca

```
    import { getStorage, ref, deleteObject } from "firebase/storage";

    const storage = getStorage();

    const thisRef = ref(storage, `post/${id}`);

    deleteObject(thisRef).then(() => {
        // Borrado con éxito
    }).catch((error) => {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución , te sugerimos revisar [answer], agrega por favor de que forma ayudaría la información que compartes a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, saludos.